# Exception thrown in executing Custom Errors page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, custom-errors

I have an MVC4 application, I'm trying to configure a custom error page, however when I force an exception I get the following:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

What I've done so far:

First I set the following in the web.config in `<system.web>`:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

I've tried `Error.aspx` and `~/Views/Shared/Error.aspx` (that's the location of Error.aspx)

Here is Error.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Error1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        An error occured.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Registering global filter (in Global.asax):

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

So I'm at a loss. How can I debug this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I think I ended up going in a different direction. I do remember the issue stemming from `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />`. The defaultRedirect will use MVC's routing, so you need to have a controller action "Error" that returns the "Error.aspx" view.